# Windows 7 laptop no longer connecting to Windows Home Server

Tags: windows-7, windows-home-server

When I got this laptop I set it up with a Windows Home Server connector, and it backed up perfectly for a few months; then suddenly it stopped being able to access the server by name. I can ping the IP fine; the homegroup connects to the other Win7 machine on the network fine. The server shows up under "Network" under "Other Devices" which is the same as it does on the working Win7 machine, but when I type in the machine name in Windows Explorer like \myserver, I get the generic 0x80004005 error.

There are hundreds of suggestions on the Interwebs for this problem, and I think I've tried all of them: disabling IP6, fiddling with the discovery settings, changing the homegroup, changing the workgroup. Some people say that changing the computer description causes it to work. I didn't believe it, but I tried it, and it didn't work for me :)

Chasing this issue I've upgraded to Win7 Service pack 1, IE9, the latest version of the WiFi adapter. I'm at a loss.

So I have two questions: First, where does Win7 get its list of machine names from? If I knew that I might be able to figure out why it won't find this one.

Second, are there any particular TCP/IP packets I could sniff for to see what's not being returned properly?

Any other ideas?